# Axiom or WPF 3D?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, axiom

I've done some simple sample apps with 3D WPF, but I feel like I'm gonna have to write a full layer on top of it if I want to manage objects in a simple way. Let me explain.

I need to import objects from other modeling software (solidworks for example) and then define its own coordinate system. I'll need to control trajectories and poses of said objects using this new coordinate system.

I also need to define some simple shading and defining textures. I'm not using full screen. The viewport will be based within a WPF application.

Should I invest time on raw WPF or is it worthy to take a look on Axiom?

Answer (score 3):

I cant comment on axiom, but i can on wpf 3d.

If you require performance, large numbers of polygons or transparencies, then wpf isnt the right tool. perhaps directx or xna is.